# How to get macros to work when changing sheet names in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

I made a macro that deletes data within a cell range in 20 sheets. I did this before I named the sheets so I was having subscript errors as the macro is referring to sheet names that don't exist any more.

I've opted to use the codeName e.g `Sheet4` as this should never change (as someone else suggested on another question). However the macro breaks as soon as it hits this part of the code.

```vb
Sheet4.Range("TimeSheet4[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheet5.Range("TimeSheet45[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheet6.Range("TimeSheet456[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheet7.Range("TimeSheet4567[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

It was done like this previously and worked but I was intending to tidy the code.

```vb
Sheets("Employee 2 ").Select
Range("TimeSheet4[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Employee 3").Select
Range("TimeSheet45[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Employee 4").Select
Range("TimeSheet456[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Employee 5").Select
Range("TimeSheet4567[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: `First of all i'm new to VBA but i'm enjoying messing about with it.`In that case I would highly recommend reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: reading, thank you

Comment: Is there only one table on each sheet ?

Comment: yeah its the same table in the same format on each sheet, basically the macro just clears down all the data and creates a empty clear file ready to be worked on - rotas and timesheets

Answer (score 0):

### Clear First Tables

- If each table is the first table in each worksheet, the following will do the job.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub clearFirstTables()
    
    Const Cols As String = "[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Range(ws.ListObjects(1).Name & Cols).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Or you could use this if there are several per worksheet or if they're not the first tables:

```
Sub clearAllTables()
    
    Const Cols As String = "[[Start Time]:[Holiday]]"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Range(tbl.Name & Cols).ClearContents
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next tbl
    Next ws

End Sub
```